# resizing a MDI Tabbed Group

Tags: c++, mfc, tabs, resize

Using C++, MFC, I have an application with MDI Tabbed Groups.   I have written code to 
1
vote
0answers
21 views
programmatically create new tab groups and move tabs around.  That all works fine.

But I am having trouble setting the size of the tab groups I make.  By default, the groups are given a size that is half of the available space.   I couldn't find an official size method on the tab control class.  So I tried SetWindowPos() and MoveWindow() on the group controls instead.  That seems to have an impact, but not a full impact.

For example, lets say I want group A to be 10% of the frame window's area, while group B takes 90%.  When I issue calls to SetWindowPos() or MoveWindow(), I get about 30%:70% instead of 10%:90% I asked for.  It seems like it wants to do what I said, but it is fighting it.

I also tried calling the tab control's AutoSizeWindow(FALSE) method beforehand.
But that didn't help.

Any ideas?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my mistake.  MoveWindow() works fine.
I just didn't notice that each tabgroup needed a rect with it's own origin.  (every left would be 0)
I tried to setup rectangles that were in frame window coordinates.